# Error with recursive deletion in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, delete-file

I am currently uninstalling some software that generated data for a large number of files, all `.jpg` and `.nfo` and I would like to delete these files. I am attempting to use PowerShell to perform this operation and the command I have tried is:

```
del /S *.jpg
```

And received the following as a result:

> Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*.jpg'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + del /S *.jpg
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Thanks!

Comment: It is CMD command, but not PowerShell one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
Get-ChildItem {Path to root of folder to search from} -Recurse | Where-Object (($_.FullName -like "*.jpg") -or ($_.FullName -like "*.nfo")) | Remove-Item -Force
```

I'm yet to test this as I'm writing on my iPhone using the app, so if it's wrong let me know and I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**

- *Either*: **Run your `cmd.exe` command as-is, by prefixing it with `cmd --% /c`**:
  `cmd --% /c del /S *.jpg`
  `--%`, the stop-parsing symbol, tells PowerShell to stop parsing the remaining arguments and pass them through as-is (except for expanding `%<name>%` environment variable references) - see `Get-Help about_Parsing`.
- ***Or*: Preferably, use PowerShell's native `Remove-Item` cmdlet**:
  `Remove-Item * -Recurse -Include *.jpg -WhatIf`
  Note how [common parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) `-WhatIf` conveniently allows you to *preview* the operation before committing to it; see `Get-Help Remove-Item`.

  - *Caution*: As of PSv5.1, the `Remove-Item`, `Copy-Item` and `Move-Item` cmdlets and, to a lesser extent, `Get-ChildItem` are notoriously finicky when it comes to recursive operations and the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters - there are many subtleties.
    In general, however, **PowerShell's cmdlets are far more powerful than their `cmd.exe` counterparts, and any effort to learn how to use them effectively is well spent - not least because you'll soon be able to use PowerShell on *Unix* platforms as well**.

---

`cmd.exe` commands like `del` and `dir` are built into `cmd.exe` and cannot be called *directly* from PowerShell; to invoke them, you must invoke `cmd.exe` explicitly, using `cmd /c`, as shown above.

**What may be confusing is that PowerShell defines *aliases* for its *own* commands (cmdlets) named for their *roughly* equivalent `cmd.exe` counterparts.**
The real names of PowerShell cmdlets are very different, following a verbose, but [very consistent naming scheme](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) (that even governs naming of *PowerShell-native* aliases).

For instance, `del` is an alias for PowerShell's `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

This aliasing is a double-edged sword: on the one hand, it makes it easier for people who are used to `cmd.exe` (batch programming) to discover their PowerShell counterparts; on the other hand, it obscures the fact that **PowerShell's command-line syntax is quite different**.

**To learn what command PowerShell actually invokes when you type a name, use `Get-Command`**:

```
> Get-Command del

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                           
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                           
Alias           del -> Remove-Item
```

- **For a quick overview of a command's syntax, invoke it with `-?` or use `Get-Help`**:
  `del /?`
- For more extensive help, use `Get-Help -detailed <cmd>` or `Get-Help -full <cmd>`; **see `Get-Help -detailed Get-Help`**.

As you can see, you can pass `-?` to and invoke `Get-Help` with the *alias* forms of commands as well.